# Are there any 'official' templates used for writing out adventures in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-preparation, online-resources

I'm trying to seat this question in the idea of "Tools and equipment used while playing table-top RPGs" and not just have it be a matter of opinion. Please feel free to suggest edits so I can make this a better question if needed.

Like [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59397/are-there-any-templates-available-for-creating-new-backgrounds-in-dnd-5e) asking about templates for creating new backgrounds, I'm looking for templates that help a DM write "episodes" or "adventures", writing out the details for an adventure that may take one or more real-life sessions to play through. I'm an experienced DM who can plan out adventures but I'm looking for an accepted tool (like in the answer to the linked question) that people use to translate my session notes into a format others can easily read.

Any official templates are acceptable, though it would be helpful if they were industry standard and used by DMs to avoid this being a brainstorming question.

Comment: as rescoped to ask about the official guideline, it's on topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Dungeon Masters Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com/) has a section dedicated to [resources for DMG creators](https://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=0_0_45476_0_0_0_0_0&src=fid45476). In particular there is an [official template](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170830/DMs-Guild-Creator-Resource--Adventure-Template) you can download for free along with artwork you can use for DMs Guild products, even sample maps. Please read the [license agreement](https://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/categories/1260801293870-Content-Creator-QuestionsInformation) to see if DMs Guild is the right approach for your adventures, there is even a [handy chart](https://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/articles/217520927-Ownership-and-License-OGL-Questions) to see what is allowed.